# How do I display active record in codeigniter with multiple controllers?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building my comment module and trying to get the active records to display on view. Seems simple however I have a lot going on and using a separate model and controller then what the view is being generated from.

So I have a profile page ( where I'm trying to get the results to display )

Controller:

```
public function profile() 
      {
            $this->load->helper('url'); //Include this line
            $this->load->helper('date');
            $this->load->library('session');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $session_id = $this->session->userdata('id'); //Ensure that this session is valid


            //TRYING TO MAKE A VARIABLE WITHT THE $_GET VALUE
            $user_get = $this->uri->segment(3); // Modify this line


            // LOAD THE CORRECT USER
            $this->load->model('account_model');
            $user = $this->account_model->user($user_get); //(suggestion) you want to pass the id here to filter your record

            $data['user'] = $user;
            $data['session_id'] = $session_id;




            if($user_get != $user['id'] || !$user_get)
            {
                $data['main_content'] = 'account/notfound';
                $this->load->view('includes/templates/profile_template', $data);
            }
            else
            {

            if($user_get == $session_id) //Modify this line also
            {
                $data['profile_icon'] = 'edit';
            }
            else
            {
                $data['profile_icon'] = 'profile';
            }
            $sharpie = $this->sharpie($user);
            $data['sharpie'] = $sharpie;
            $data['main_content'] = 'account/profile';
            $this->load->view('includes/templates/profile_template', $data);
            }

        }
```

Now I have a new controller for my comments I'm trying to display:

```
public function airwave() {
        $this->load->helper('date');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $airwave_get = $this->uri->segment(3); 
        $this->load->model('community_model');
        $airwave = $this->coummunity_model->airwave($airwave_get); 
        $data['airwave'] = $airwave;
        $data['main_content'] = 'account/profile';
        $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
    }
```

with this model:

```
public function airwave($id=null) 
        {
            if(is_null($id)) {
                $session = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
                $commenter_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
            }else{
                $commenter_id = intval($id);
            }

            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM airwaves_comments WHERE from_id=$commenter_id");
            if($query->num_rows()==1)
            {
               $data = $query->result_array();
               return $data[0];
            //above returns the single row you need to the controller as an array.
            //to the $data['user'] variable.

            }

        }
```

and trying to display it on this view ( which is generated by the profile function )

```
<div class="profile_airwave_comment_text">
    <?php echo $airwave['comment'];?>
</div>
```

I just can't seem to get it to pass the array variable I've created properly to that view?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the last point where you're sure the data is correct?  (database, model, controller, view)

Comment: that's the problem, is I can't figure out how to test my data's validity due to not being able to print it anywhere

Comment: Add a print_r($airwave); after statement $airwave = $this->coummunity_model->airwave($airwave_get);

Comment: @jtp that's the problem is I can't get anything to print on the view

Comment: That could be problematic :) Are you getting any output in the CodeIgniter logs? I would probably start troubleshooting by adding echo "here 1", echo "here 2", etc. statements after every line after the $airwave_get statement to try to get any output from the controller.

Comment: Are you trying to use the `airwave()` controller while on the `profile()` page? Is that the idea? If so, check http://stackoverflow.com/q/6052746/183254 - It should work with ajax, but it won't natively. In the meantime, you can visit http://example.com/airwave/123 to verify airwave is working.

Comment: @LightningWrist - you can print from absolutely anywhere in codeigniter.  If you're seeing a blank page even after printing something, you may have a parse error or a routing issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first glaring thing I see wrong is in you model's airwave function:

```
        if($query->num_rows()==1)
        {
           $data = $query->result_array();
           return $data[0];
```

You are assuming that there will only be one result in your query, so if there are more or less than one, your $data array will bever be set.

Also, even then you are only returning the first element in the array. I am not seeing anywhere in your question that you want to return only one.

Finally, in your view, if you now return the full array, and not only one element, you will have to do a foreach statement.

EDIT: please see suggested solution.

In your model, don't worry about the check for the amount of data in the result array. This will come later. Simply do:

```
return $query->result_array();
```

Now, keep your controller as is, but adapt your view:

```
<div class="profile_airwave_comment_text">
<?php 
    if (isset($airwave) && is_array($airwave) && !empty($airwave))
    {
        foreach ($airwave as $wave)
        {
            echo $wave['comment'];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'No comments found...';
    }
?>
</div>
```

This should work, and if not, at least let you know that no comments were fond, and thus check your database.

HTH!

Comment: Ok I'm a little new at this so thanks for pointing that out. I've gone ahead and changed the query from ==1 to >1. Also how would I do the foreach in order to be able to pull all of the elements in my area to use? meaning on the view I would be able to pull them by $airwave['id'],$airwave['from_id'] etc... so I'm unsure how to put that array in the foreach. <?php
       foreach($airwave as $airwave) {
        
        echo $airwave['comment'];
       }
      ?>

Comment: I tried this and it gave me a invalid foreach argument error. <div class="profile_airwave_comment_text">
      <?php
       foreach($airwave as $aw) {
        
        echo $aw['comment'];
       }
      ?>
     </div>

Answer (score 0):

If your using HMVC, simply call the module from inside the profile view, ie:

```
echo Modules::run('comments/profileComments', $user->id);
```

Else:
You would need to create a new method in the loader class, to load in the controller seperate from routing.

If your really after a quick fix until you come up with a better alternative, you could(depending if both controllers live in the same directory) just include the 'comments' controller in your 'profile' controller and try something like this:

**{Cons: CI Pagination wont work!}**

**application/controllers/profile.php**

```
include 'Comments' . EXT;

class Profile extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct ()
    {
        parent::__construct () ;

    }

    public function index( $user_id ){

        $commentsPartialView = call_user_func_array(array(new Comments(), "getProfileComments"), array($user_id));

        return $this->load->view($this->template, array(
               'view' => 'profiles/_index',
               'comments' => $commentsPartialView
        ));
    }


}
```

-

**application/controllers/Comments.php**

```
class Comments extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct ()
    {
        parent::__construct () ;

    }

    public function getProfileComments( $user_id ){

        $user_comments = ''; //pull from DB

        //set third param to TRUE for partial view, without main template
        return $this->load->view('comments/show', array(
               'user_comments' => $user_comments
        ), TRUE);
    }


}
```